# How to include 'jni.h' file using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, java-native-interface

I am trying to compile my `C++` project using `CMake` on my `Mac M1 Pro 12.0.1`.

This is my simple directory structure:
[image]

In my `foo.cpp`, I am including `jni.h` header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.h"
#include <vector>
#include <jni.h>
void foo()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

This is my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

project("myapplication")


add_library(my_app SHARED main.cpp foo.cpp)

target_include_directories(my_app PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

    if(APPLE)
        
    
        set(JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH "$ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include")
        set(JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 "$ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include/darwin")
        set(JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH "$ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include")
        message("JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH = ${JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH}")
        find_package(JNI REQUIRED)
        if (JNI_FOUND)
            message (STATUS "JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS=${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
            message (STATUS "JNI_LIBRARIES=${JNI_LIBRARIES}")
        endif()
        target_include_directories(my_app PUBLIC ${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    endif()
```

I am getting `CMake` output as:

```
-- Found JNI: /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework  
-- JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS=/Users/vmangal/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home/include;/Users/vmangal/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin;/Users/vmangal/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home/include
-- JNI_LIBRARIES=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework;/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/vmangal/my/practice/cmake/build
```

My `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is set to `/Users/vmangal/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk`

But during `make` command, I am getting compilation error:

```
/Users/vmangal/my/practice/cmake/foo.cpp:4:10: fatal error: 'jni.h' file not found
#include <jni.h>
```

Am I missing something in `CMakeLists.txt` ?

Comment: what did you see if using `cmake --build ... -v` to get the compilation cmd line ?

Comment: Do you have jni.h installed ? what is the output of `find -L $JAVA_HOME -type f -iname "jni.h"` ?

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindJNI.html

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and found that when setting variables this way

```
    set(JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH "$ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include")
```

i was getting wrong imports for `C_INCLUDES` and `CXX_INCLUDES`. Like this (see in CMakeFiles/my_app.dir/flags.make):

```
C_INCLUDES = -I/include -I/include/darwin
CXX_INCLUDES = -I/include -I/include/darwin
```

Which basically which meant that $ENV{JAVA_HOME} was an empty string.
After I set the full paths in CMakeLists

```
    set(JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@17/17.0.3/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/include)
```

everything started working correctly.

So the conclusion is that if you want to run cmake and use `$ENV{JAVA_HOME}` – use syntax `JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java/home cmake ...`

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindJNI.html

Comment: it doesn't work for me...

Comment: Well, your answer suggests a very wrong practice of hardcoding paths.

Comment: Actually I didn't suggest any kind of practice. I described my experience with this error and I pointed out the points that are worth paying attention to

Comment: Answers are judged by solutions they propose. So your answer either describes a harmful solution (bad answer) or it doesn't propose a solution (bad, not an answer).

Comment: My solution is not a harmful (once again, I'm not suggesting to hardcode the paths), I suggest solving the problem through an explicit set env.